# Why is there a delayed in establishing a connection to a database using NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

excuse me for not knowing this, but I would like to know why there is a delay when I try to establish a connection to the database.

I am basically pulling data from a database to display the info back onto a `UITableView` but there seems to be a delay in the connection establishment.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [self fetchFromDatabase];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [self fetchFromDatabase];
    
    NSLog(@"FOUR");
}

- (void)fetchFromDatabase
{
    // The URL of the database
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:SDTET_DATABASE_SCHEDULE];
    
    // Establish the connection to the database
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[ [NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[ [NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"ONE !");
     } ];
}
```

However, the output looks like so:

> FOUR
>
> FOUR
>
> ONE !

Why doesn't `ONE !` get printed out first?

How can I ensure the connection occurs before the numberOfSections is called, if possible?

Thanks

Comment: Internet connections are nondeterministic by their very nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ONE gets printed last because you are calling an asynchronous method.

You can follow the flow of the program (which method calls which in what order). If we let our imagination stretch a bit, we could say that when a method is synchronous, it basically **"says" to the next line of code** to wait for it (the method) to finish. 
However, if a method is asynchronous, it say "don't wait for me". The URL request method you are using is asynchronous. That means it starts to do its job but nobody waits, the execution of code continues in the next line **immediately**.

[image: Asynchronous method in code]

There is a piece in the puzzle that will clarify this more. The request method needs to be fed a **completion block** as a parameter. Explaining blocks is out of scope here, but you need to understand what block is to fully grasp the solution to your problem. 
Suffice to say, once this asynchronous method finishes its job (which can be a long time and **this** is one of the reasons for asynchronous approach really), the block is invoked and executed. 
[image: Block in the method]

So to answer your last question, you need to trigger a refresh on your table view, which you achieve by calling 
`[self.tableView reloadData];` **inside** the block. There is a nice logic here, since you know the block is executed ONLY after the asynchronous method concludes its work, you will refresh your table view knowing you have the updated data from db.

Comment: thanks for the graphical representation! Does that mean I can just remove the call in numberOfSections and just reload the table in completion block?

Comment: PS: Methods are asynchronous not because they have that word in their signature, but because authors decided to implement them that way internaly. AFAIK there is no way in objective C to find our prpgramatically about asynchronicity. You need to read the Class documentation to find out.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it is an asynchronous request (meaning it doesn't necessarily happen immediately). It's a huge principle of computer science and it a much bigger concept than just Objective-C or iOS development.

In your case, you can get rid of the fetch being called in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and you can just call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in your `completionHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a delay because network access is slow. Sometimes it's REALLY slow.

Sometimes you can get a response in less than a second, and other times it can take the better part of a minute to get your response.

You should always write your network code to be asynchronous, which means that you submit the request with a method that returns immediately. Your program continues to run, and then you get notified once the response has been received.

That's what is going on with your code.

You don't want to send the request to load your data in numberOfSectionsInTableView. You should send the network request as early as possible, preferably before the view controller that will display the results is displayed.

However, it's pretty common to display a table view before you have the data to fill it. You might show an empty table view with a message that the data is loading, or with a progress dialog. In other cases you might know how many cells to display, and have the text data but not the images. In that case you might populate your cells with placeholder images. Once the data loads you can update the display.

In your case you should write your numberOfSectionsInTableView and `numberOfRowsInSection:` methods to return zero, and then make the completion method of your network call tell the table view to reload itself.